# Grouping Dataframe[groupby()] by python3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'order':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],'quantity':[1,1,2,3,3,4]})


df_out = df.order.repeat(df.quantity).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
df_out['grp'] = df_out.index // 4
df_out.groupby(['grp','order'])['order'].count().to_frame(name='quantity')
```

output :

```
      quantity
grp order          
0   A             1
    B             1
    C             2
1   D             3
    E             1
2   E             2
    F             2
3   F             2
```

In  groupby() function I have got my desired result.
But when i try to `Concat()` with `df1`,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'order':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],'quantity':[1,1,2,3,3,4]})
```

I found that `0` from `grp` is assigned to only first row

`grp order

0   A             1`

not as

`quantity
grp order

0   A             1
0   B             1
0   C             2`

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get after `groupby(*multiple_columns*).*some_action*` is a `Dataframe` with `MultiIndex`. You can reset it:

```
ans = (
    df_out
    .groupby(['grp', 'order'])['order']
    .count()
    .to_frame(name='quantity')
    .reset_index())
```

Then you may use any column as index and drop that column:

```
ans.index = ans['grp']
ans = ans.drop('grp', axis=1)
```

`ans` is:

```
    order  quantity
grp                
0       A         1
0       B         1
0       C         2
1       D         3
1       E         1
2       E         2
2       F         2
3       F         2
```